# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent, get unique and sorted

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem in laravel when I get unique values from table column and trying to sort them.

```
$auctions = Model::all('name')->unique('name')->sortBy('name', 'ASC');
```

When I use php `sort()` or `->sortBy` it says `Method Not allowed`.

How can I sort this collection?

Comment: And that error is *what*?

Comment: How do you call sort() or sortBy()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

```
$raw_auctions = Model::all('name')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
$auctions = $raw_auctions->unique('name');
```